# How to click a button and pass arguments tied with NO. variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a button to my excel worksheet db1 that can add one agument (an integer value) in worksheet db2. 
the code is like

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("db2").Range("c2").Value = Sheets("db2").Range("c2").Value + 1
Sheets("db1").Range("a2").Value = Sheets("db1").Range("a2").Value + 1
End Sub
```

the function is 
click  MS button in worksheet db1, then  cell c2 increase 1 in worksheet db2
[image]
because of auto sorting in worksheet db2, the MS button and cell c2 relation may change.

if there is anyway to realize click button1_click  it will 1 value right 2 cell  if it match No.=1 
and

click button2_click  it will 1 value right 2 cell  if it match No.=2
and

click button3_click  it will 1 value right 2 cell  if it match No.=3
etc...

Comment: Use `Find` to catch which cell you need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, use `Find` to catch which cells you need to update. Utilize the `Application.Caller` to see what `Text` you are looking for.

Assign the following to all your three buttons/shapes:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("db1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("db2")

With ws2 'Change accordingly
    Dim rw As Long: rw = .Range("B2:B4").Find(ws1.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text).Row
    .Cells(rw, 3).Value = .Cells(rw, 3).Value + 1
End With

End Sub
```